# iphone badges management through push notifications

Tags: iphone, badge

we need iphone to increase the badge numeric value on push notification arrival without initializing the application. f.e. a notification with a badge values of 1 arrives and is shown on the app icon. then another notification with badge value of 2 arrives. 2 replaces 1 on the badge, but we would like to make it 1+2=3. is a server side work around is the only way to deal with this issue?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, server side work around is the only way..

What value you will send from server will be set to the icon.

Answer (score 2):

what ever value you are sending to app, that value will be displayed on top of App Icon, either the value may be 4 or 90 or 100.. if you want to do like 1+2=3, just increment the badge number dynamically i.e 
`Present badge number = Present badge number+2;`

Comment: the application isn't running when a notification arrives to the handset and the badge value is updated.

Comment: why application is not running?

Comment: 'cos you can close the application, but this doesn't mean an external push notification won't arrive. the badge is updated even if you choose not to open an application.

Answer (score 0):

just pass "**badge:+2**" to APP  , the number increased

Comment: i use javapns library to submit push notification to apn. unfortunately the only badge related method i can find there is addBadge(int). have you done this editing json or something?

Comment: can you modify the javapns code?   you must edit the payload to app as "+2" to work

Comment: urbanairship.com   look at this site , and test on it, you can edit payload yourself , just have a test

Comment: urbanairship runs their own notification network, they are not related to apn, aren't them?

Comment: i mean that you test the payload if it is possible to add the number of badge count , if count you should modify the code of javanps :)

Comment: i manged a way to replace a badge value in the json itself, but this doesn't work. notifications with "+n" style badges do nothing on device.